# Deletion of records who created it

Tags: profile, delete, sharing-rule, owd

For example am the owner of the record then only i should be able to delete the record, And i should not be able to delete records created by others.I cant give ModifyAll permission to that profile as it is not Admin profile. And OWD is private ,What is the other option?

Comment: Hi. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/334245/edit) your question as it isn't clear just what the problem you face is. A user should be able to delete records where they are the Owner (rather that CreatedBy). Are you correctly managing the Owner here? What sort of user is it (a full platform user, a community user, a guest user)?

Comment: Updated the post, hope you understood my query. Delete option should be given only to the records createdBy the user "X" ,not for the other records which are not created by "X" user. If Y has created the record he should have option of deleting not "X".  @PhilW

Comment: If you use Owner you can do this via standard functionality in Salesforce. If you insist on using CreatedBy then you need to add some automation (e.g. a flow or a trigger) that verifies that the contextual user for a record deletion is the same as the CreatedBy for the record.

Comment: I want to do on owner how can we do that through configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Owner, rather than CreatedBy, you can deal with this as follows:

- Set the OWD sharing for your object type to Private or Read Only.
- Do not set up sharing rules for this object type.
- Ensure the user profile has the ability to Delete.
- Ensure that the Owner is always set on record creation using the contextual user (so it matches CreatedBy).

That's it. At that point your users will only be able to view, edit and/or delete their own records (it depends on what you select for OWDs).

On the other hand if you want to use CreatedBy then you need to add automation (such as a trigger) that verifies that the contextual user's ID matches that of the CreatedBy and where it doesn't causes a failure. (I would suggest a record-triggered flow on deletion but these don't seem to be able to cause a failure or test the contextual user without dropping into Apex anyway.)

It would be as simple as doing something like the following on before delete via a trigger on your relevant record object type (I call it `MyRecord__c` here):

```
for (MyRecord__c record : Trigger.old) {
    if (UserInfo.getUserId() != record.CreatedById) {
        record.addError('You are not allowed to delete records you didn\'t create');
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if i want to add permission set, in this For example if permission set is assigned then anyone can delete.

Comment: No. If following the second option, using the CreatedById, you already need to provide the ability to delete via permissions regardless of whether this is via a profile or permission set. This loop is checking that the user deleting is the user who created. Additionally, if taking the first option, permission sets don't affect sharing and you already need to ensure the user has the permission to delete their own records.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what i mean is if user X is manager but if he wants to delete the User Y record who reports to X ,then how is it possible?

Comment: You can do that very easily using role-based Sharing Groups with the first approach.

Comment: Ok i will it a try , thank you so much Phil :)

Comment: Thinking to add a condition in code itself by checking if user is not assigned to permission set then only the created owner can delete orelse anyone can delete who has PS.

Comment: That sort of thing is usually done by having [custom permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/custom_perms_overview.htm), not a named permission set.

Comment: Yes i have custom permission even how i can use that?

Comment: The referenced documentation tells you how.

Comment: Thank you so much.! phil

Answer (score 0):

You can give Delete permission on the Profiles for the desired objects which they should be able to remove. That should work for you.

Comment: I have tried this but user can delete others created records too. my requirement is if createdby me then only i should be able to delete the record not others record.